# Unable to access component attributes in specifc getter methods

Tags: apex, visualforce, visualforce-component, dynamic-visualforce

I am setting a string as an attribute `someString` in a custom component `tabComponent` from the mainPage. I know that we cannot access the attribute in the constructor of the VF component controller, but we can access the attributes in a getter method.  Now, I am able to access the attribute in methods which are returning `String` or `Integer`, but the attribute is coming as `null` if I access it from the method returning a complex type like `Component.Apex.OutputPanel`.

**Main VF page:**

```
<apex:page>
    <c:tabComponent someString="panelId"/>
</apex:page>
```

**VF Component:**

```
<apex:component controller="ComponentClass">
    <apex:attribute type="String" description="Some String" name="someString" assignTo="{!someAttribute}"/>
    {!theString}<br/> //This prints panelId
    {!someInteger} //This prints 20
    <apex:dynamicComponent componentValue="{!Panel}"/> //This renders a Panel with the Id=somePanelnull. Which is not correct.

</apex:component>
```

**VF Component Controller:**

```
public class ComponentClass {
    public String someAttribute {get;set;}

    //this method is where my problem is
    public Component.Apex.OutputPanel getPanel() {
        system.debug('the value of the string '+ someAttribute); //this always returns null
        Component.Apex.OutputPanel outputPanel = new Component.Apex.OutputPanel();
        outputPanel.Id = 'somePanel'+someAttribute;
        return outputPanel;
    }

    //I can access the attribute value here.
    public String gettheString() {
        return someAttribute;
    }

    //I can access the attribute value here as well
    public Integer getsomeInteger() {

        system.debug('the value of the String '+ someAttribute);
        return 20;
    }
}
```

Need urgent help to resolve this.

Comment: In the VF component you have 'theString' and 'someInteger' that don't appear in the controller. Should one of these be 'someAttribute'?

Comment: These are the name of the methods in the controller.

Comment: Ah, I see the getX methods now. My fault for checking the question on a cellphone. Maybe try putting system.debug statements in the someAttribute get and set bodies. You could also give it a default value in a constructor. Then check the order of the debug statements in the log.

Comment: See also http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/10763/dymamic-components-execution-order-issue

Answer (score 1):

I agree that this behavior is not analogous to the pattern. Its evaluating differently when it comes to dynamic components. This issue is being faced by many users.

[Dymamic components execution order issue](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/10763/dymamic-components-execution-order-issue)

I think currently this can help you out :

```
public class ComponentClass {
    public String someAttribute {get;set;}
     public Component.Apex.OutputPanel Panel {get;set;}

    //this method is where my problem is
    public Component.Apex.OutputPanel evaulatePanel() {
        system.debug('the value of the string '+ someAttribute); //this always returns null
        Component.Apex.OutputPanel outputPanel = new Component.Apex.OutputPanel();
        outputPanel.Id = 'somePanel'+someAttribute;
        return outputPanel;
    }

    //I can access the attribute value here.
    public String gettheString() {
        Panel  = evaulatePanel();
        return someAttribute;
    }
    public ComponentClass(){

    }
    //I can access the attribute value here as well
    public Integer getsomeInteger() {

        system.debug('the value of the String '+ someAttribute);
        return 20;
    }
}
```

**Also one of the temporary workaround could be to re-render the page after first page load.**

Comment: Thanks Amit. I have already done this. But I wanted to know why is it not working in those getter method.

Comment: At this time , we can just assume that the getters for dynamic components evaluate differently. I cannot see any documentation around it. I shall get back if I find anything concrete!@

Comment: I have modified the answer with some more research!